# Tablesorter filter on the total values

Tags: filter, tablesorter

I return the values 10 by 10 in my table using the tablesorterPager.
This ajaxProcessing code treat my values returned by json.

When I use the filters (filter-select or search), it's only applied on the 10 values returned by my controller and I want to apply it to the total rows.

```
ajaxProcessing: function(data){
   if (data && data.hasOwnProperty('rows')) {
      var r, row, c, d = data.rows,
      total = data.total_rows,
      headers = data.headers,
      rows = [],
      len = total;
      for ( r=0; r < len; r++ ) {
         row = [];
         for ( c in d[r] ) {
             if (typeof(c) === "string") {
                row.push(d[r][c]);
             }
         }
         rows.push(row);
      }
      return [ total, rows, headers ];
   }
},
```

Have you some ideas?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The `ajaxProcessing` function can only apply to the rows returned by ajax... I'm not sure what you mean by "I want to apply it to the total rows."

Comment: For example, the total can be 1000 and the rows displayed 10. I just want the filter-select to be applied on the total and not on the ten first rows. I think it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may need to use the `ajaxUrl` and `customAjaxUrl` options. With the `ajaxUrl` option you set how the filter url parameters are formatted when a filter is activated. With `customAjaxUrl` you can convert the filter url parameters set in `ajaxURl` to whatever you need to properly filter the 1000 records according to how your program works.

For example, let's say you have ajaxUrl set as follows:
`ajaxUrl: dataquery.php?{filter:filter}`

Let's say you type "John" into the first column filter in the table. This will cause `customAjaxUrl` to run and the `url` variable will be `dataquery.php?filter[0]=John`. Let's say that for the query to properly filter your 1000 records you need the url query to be `dataquery.php?name=John`. To make that conversion, add coding within the `customAjaxUrl` option to change `filter[0]` to `name` and return the converted url `dataquery.php?name=John`. This will then filter the 1000 records and return the filtered result to your table.

You may not be using php but the concept would still apply.